# Executing .sh file in Eclipse using java

Tags: installation, sh, silent

public class TestNetbeans {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "./netbeans-7.0.1-ml-linux.sh", " --silent");
        // ProcessBuilder("./netbeans-7.0.1-ml-linux.sh"," --silent"," -J-Dnb-base.jdk.location=/home/nayum/Documents/jdk1.6.0_23/jre");
        Process process = processBuilder.start();

        process.waitFor();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

This code when executed on command prompt it works fine for the silent installation of netbeans but when executed in eclipse its execution is terminated. What is the problem and solution ???

Comment: IIRC you need to explicitly run the script explicitly with the shell.

Comment: Yes I did those changes also. I wrote one new SH file containing command "./netbeans-7.0.1-ml-linux.sh --silent" and tried to execute this shell file but nothing is happening.

Comment: But the process returning value is "4". I googled it and found out that positive number means warnings are generated from process. How should I read warnings using Java? any idea

Comment: You can read the stdout and stderr from the process. So you are calling "/bin/sh script.sh" ?

Comment: String cmd2 = "./netbeans-7.0.1-ml-linux.sh --silent";
     Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd2);
     p2.waitFor();
     String line = "";
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(p2.getErrorStream()));
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
     }

Comment: Its output coming as blank

Comment: As I said you need to explicitly call the shell not just the script directly, the shebang (#!) is not evaluated if you use exec.